# How to define CRS (WGS84) of a mosaic raster file while all the parental raster files are in WGS84 in Python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, mosaic

```
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff","height": mosaic.shape[1],
             "width": mosaic.shape[2],
             "transform": out_trans,
             "crs": "+ "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"})
```

Using this code lead me wrong to define the mosaic CRS as the mosaic raster suppose to be in WGS84. After defining the mosaic in WGS84 I will project the file into a local coordinate system. How can I define a custom CRS?

I am totally a new beginner in Python. I am seeking an answer with examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if you need to do the projection or if you just want to define the new CRS in the metadata (so my answer also includes the projection step but I guess you will be able to adapt it if you only need the metadata part) :

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling

# The destination CRS from your question
dst_crs = "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"

# Open the dataset to be projected
with rio.open('/path/to/dataset/in/WGS84.tif') as src:
    # Compute the transform and the dimensions for the reprojection
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    
    # Update the metadata to include the new information about :
    # the new crs, the transform value, and the dimension
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    })

    # Open a new dataset in writing mode using these metadatas
    with rio.open('/tmp/res.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        # Reproject each band
        for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rio.band(src, i),
                destination=rio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=src.transform,
                src_crs=src.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=dst_crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

Comment: as far as I understand, dst_crs is defining the CRS for the mosaic raster, right?. what will be dst_crs for WGS84? and about the resampling part, what does it mean by resampling?

Comment: @yorkigriffin i guess I misunderstood you question (I thought you wanted to reproject your mosaic from WGS84 to the CRS written in your question). Maybe you can edit your question to show your previous steps (how your are obtaining the `mosaic` and the `out_meta` variables, etc.)